# In Xamarin the OnOptionsItemSelected is not called

Tags: android, menu, xamarin

I read different articles here about `OnOptionsItemSelected` not been called in Android, because I have the same problem in Xamarin.Android.
I have an menu in my main activity, but I haven't used **fragments** at all. The menu is read from an XML file:

```
        public override bool OnCreateOptionsMenu(IMenu menu)
    {
        MenuInflater.Inflate(Resource.Menu.main, menu);
        return base.OnCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    }
```

And then I tried to catch the ItemSelected Events by using the following code:

```
        public virtual bool OnOptionsItemSelected (IMenuItem item)
    {
        string test;
        Console.WriteLine ("Test");
        return true;
    }
```

But it doesn't work and the event is not called.
I tried other events like:

```
        public virtual bool OnMenuItemSelected (int featureId, IMenuItem item)
    {
        string test;
        Console.WriteLine ("Test");
        return true;
    }

    public void OnGroupItemClick( IMenuItem item) {
        // One of the group items (using the onClick attribute) was clicked
        // The item parameter passed here indicates which item it is
        // All other menu item clicks are handled by onOptionsItemSelected()
        int i = 0;
        string test;
        Console.WriteLine ("Test");

        test = item.MenuInfo.ToString ();

    }
```

But none of these events have been called. The menu is there, but I cannot catch the ClickedEvents.
How can I catch the ClickedEvents?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the answer. The problem was that I was using `virtual` methods.
Instead of that I had to use `override` methods.

Comment: Thanks. I had the same problem and I made the same mistake.

Answer (score 0):

Your code seems to work in a clean application (just tried on Xamarin.Android Alpha channel, latest version, on VS2013).
A few things you might try:

- Disable Fast Deployment in the project properties under Android Options
- Delete the bin and obj folders from your project folder

Besides this, are you using any external library/component?

Comment: I have disabled the Fast Deployment and delete the folders you mentioned, but nothing changed.
As external libraries and components I am using JSON.NET and Xamarin.Android.Support.v4.dll. But I am not using Xamarin.Android.Support.v4.dll in this activity.

Comment: I tried it in a clean application (with Android 4.4, API 19 on Xamarin Studio) but it didn't work. I mean the events haven't been fired, when I click on the Menu Items.

Comment: In your code you have used `override` functions and that is the reason why it is working. As I have written in the answer, the problem with my code was using `virtual` functions.